# How do I download with youtube-dl to get video title as filename?

Tags: command-line, video, downloads, youtube-dl

How the current file has been downloaded to display the original title?
When i download always like `P9pzm5b6Fxx.mp4`, when the title is `Tigerking`.

How do I set it so that it is downloaded as `tigerking.mp4`?

Comment: That is weird, for me it would download the video as `Tigerking-P9pzm5b6Fxx.mp4` if its YouTube ID is `P9pzm5b6Fxx`.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

From [`man youtube-dl`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/youtube-dl.1.html):

```
-o, --output TEMPLATE
      Output filename template.   Use  %(title)s  to  get  the  title,
      %(uploader)s  for  the  uploader  name,  %(uploader_id)s for the
      uploader  nickname  if  different,  %(autonumber)s  to  get   an
      automatically  incremented  number,  %(ext)s  for  the  filename
      extension, %(format)s for the format  description  (like  "22  -
      1280x720"  or  "HD"),  %(format_id)s  for  the  unique id of the
      format (like YouTube's itags: "137"),  %(upload_date)s  for  the
      upload date (YYYYMMDD), %(extractor)s for the provider (youtube,
      metacafe, etc), %(id)s for  the  video  id,  %(playlist_title)s,
      %(playlist_id)s,   or   %(playlist)s   (=title  if  present,  ID
      otherwise) for the playlist the video is in,  %(playlist_index)s
      for  the position in the playlist.  %(height)s and %(width)s for
      the width and height of the video format.  %(resolution)s for  a
      textual  description  of the resolution of the video format.  %%
      for a literal percent.  Use - to output to stdout.  Can also  be
      used  to  download to a different directory, for example with -o
      '/my/downloads/%(uploader)s /%(title)s-%(id)s.%(ext)s' .
```

So, presumably:

```
youtube-dl -o '%(title)s.%(ext)s' <URL-of-video>
```